# How to remove inconsistence entries which performing click event

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net

While  clicking on the button, due to slow speed, I have clicked it multiple times. What the problem is, I am getting multiple records in the db instead of getting single record. Can anyone tell how to avoid multiple instances to maintain data consistency.

Comment: You can simply use loading image to avoid multiple click.

Comment: show your code....

Comment: Didn't get you. Loading image?

Comment: Disable the button on first click

Comment: How can I handle this inconsistency of data due to slow network.Any isolation need to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the button in javascript after the first click

Comment: Actuallt trying to ignore to perform disable option.

Comment: So don't disable it. Just declare a global boolean initialized to `true` that becomes `false` when you click for the first time. You can then test it at the begining of the click event. Or else, you have to solve it in the server side.

Comment: If you take A. Wabbi's solution, remember to set that boolean back to `true` after the server operation has finished !

Comment: When the network is slow and event is clicked multiple times,do it will check for the Boolean?Need to do any transaction isolation?

Comment: Sure. This happens at the client side. No network engaged.

Comment: In a similar way: declare a boolean variable in the `Session` initialized to `true`. The first command of the `Click` event would test this boolean. If it is `true`, make it `false`, do the work then make it `true` again. If it is `false` (which means second or third click ...), just `return` to terminate the event without doing the work again.

Comment: What if I am opening the click event on two browser at the same time and almost on the same time I am clicking it (just to check for consistency and netwoek delays).How can I solve this issue to not to enter multiple records.

Comment: The two browsers will have different sessions. Anyway, you can store the boolean in the ViewState rather than the session. ViewState is page-related and it is different for the two browsers even if they use the same session.